# get array values with a function in PHP

Tags: php

What is the proper way to create a function to get array values from a query? I am getting "Undefined index: page_title" error.
However I can get the value without function like: echo $row->page_title;
Or echo $query[0]->title;

```
function get_page($id) {

    $db = new DB();

    $query = $db->get_rows("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = :id ", array('id' => $_GET['id']) );

    foreach ($query as $row) {
        $page_id = $row->id;
        $page_title = $row->title;
    }

    return $query;

}

$page = get_page(1);

echo $page['page_title'];
```

here is my database class:

```
function get_rows($query, $values=array(), $fetchType = FETCH_OBJ)
{
    $sth = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    if(is_array($values) && (sizeof($values) > 0))
    {
        foreach($values as $key=>$val)
        {
            $key = is_numeric($key) ? ($key + 1) : $key;
            $sth->bindValue($key,$val); 
        }
    }
    if($sth->execute())
        return $sth->fetchAll($fetchType);
}
```

Comment: what you are using for db connection mysql or mysqli or PDO

Comment: Depends, are the ids in the table unique?  Then you wouldn't need to loop them.

Comment: I am using a PDO database class

Comment: then you need to prepare first your query then execute and then use either fetchArray OR fetchAll

Comment: And you're sure that `get_rows()` is returning an array of objects?

Comment: ids are unique but actually I am trying to learn the proper way to write this kind of function. So I may use for column names are not unique

Comment: if you fetch it as Array, you can then count the number of rows and then use a for loop to access them all.

Comment: yes it returns an array. I can get the value without function. ex: echo $row->page_title;

Comment: so are you wanting to be able to grab data from a diffrent column but with the same id while just reusing the same function?

Comment: certainly that's what I am trying to do :)

Answer (score 0):

To make the function reusable, I would rewrite it the following way

```
function get_page($id, $col) {
  $db = new DB();

  $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = :id');
  $query->execute(array(':id' => $id));
  $results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

  return $results[0][$col]; 
}

$page = get_page(1, 'page_title');
echo $page;
```

I skipped the foreach as you said that all id's are unique so you should only ever have 1 result

Also it may not be a bad idea to add some error checking to make sure you do get back what you expect from the query and to make sure it is not empty.

Edit: Sorry if the syntax is a little off, dont have anything to test the code against quickly.

Comment: `return $results[0][$col];` instead of `return $results[0]['.$col.'];`